# How Can I Avoid CDK Bootstrap When Not Needed?

Tags: aws-cdk

Running cdk bootsrtrap is slow, even if the environment has already been bootstrapped.  How can I avoid bootstrapping an environment that already has it?

Answer (score 3):

Use the AWS CLI to check for the bootstrap stack already existing.  This is much faster than re-running bootstrap.

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name CDKToolkit 2>&1 > /dev/null || \
    cdk bootstrap aws://$(aws sts get-caller-identity | jq -r .Account)/us-east-1
```